# Trying to get the number of warns a users has and send it discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, discord, discord.py

I get a new error now. I edited smth now and i get this error. What to do. New code is given below

````
 @commands.command()
  async def warn(self, ctx, user:discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    user_id = user.id
    if collection.count_documents({"userid":user.id}) == 0:
      collection.insert_one({"userid":user.id,"count":0})

    if reason == None:
      return await ctx.send("Please mention a reason!")
    elif user == None:
      return await ctx.send("Please mention a member!")
    
    user = collection.find_one({"userid":user.id})
 
    current_count = user["count"]
    new_count = current_count + 1
    collection.update_one({"userid":user.id}, {"$set": {"count": new_count}}) 

    em = discord.Embed(title = "Member Warned!", description = f"Warned {user.mention} for **{reason}** | They now have {new_count} warnings!", timestamp = ctx.message.created_at, color = 0xFF0000)
    em.set_footer(text=f'Warned By {ctx.author} | ID: {ctx.author.id}', icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)``` This is the code
````

Ignoring exception in command warn:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/runner/HorribleSentimentalParallelprocessing/cogs/warn.py", line 30, in warn
collection.update_one({"userid":user.id}, {"$set": {"count": new_count}})
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'id'```

Comment: You’ve already asked this question two times before, please be patient until someone answers them.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the user without any warnings. You were also adding warnings to the author himself instead of the user.

```py
@commands.command()
  async def warn(self, ctx,user: discord.Member, *,reason=None):
    if collection.count_documents({"userid":user.id}) == 0:
        collection.insert_one({"userid":user.id,"count":0})

    if reason is None:
      return await ctx.send("Please mention a reason!")
    
    user_doc = collection.find_one({"userid":user.id})
 
    current_count = user_doc["count"]
    new_count = current_count + 1
    collection.update_one({"userid":user.id}, {"$set": {"count": new_count}}) 

    em = discord.Embed(title = "Member Warned!", description = f"Warned {user.mention} for **{reason}** | They now have {new_count} warnings!", timestamp = ctx.message.created_at, color = 0xFF0000)
    em.set_footer(text=f'Warned By {ctx.author} | ID: {ctx.author.id}')
    collection.update_one({"userid":ctx.author.id}, {"$inc": {"count": 1}}) 
    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```